# Is it possible to run a task in a dag based on the status of another task in the same dag?

Tags: python, dependencies, task, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I need to get the status of a task 'A' and trigger a task 'B' only if the task A is not in running state. Is there a possible way to do this in airflow?

Answer (score 0):

No, you could depend on a task only after it is success, failed(upstream_failed) or even ignore its status, but you cannot depends on a task's not running status, not running means one of None, scheduled, queued, successed, failed, upstream_failed, skipped, there is no this option.

Comment: But is there any other way to do this? I have a task that should run only when another task is not running at that time. Like in autosys we can give n(jobname) to do this